# Transistor problem (traffic light)

Tags: transistors

I am trying to create a traffic light circuit using transistor. The problem is that no current flows into the system when the power is on. How do I rectify this problem? Thx for thee help!

My circuit: [image]

The schematic I followed:

[image]

Comment: Are you building a real circuit or using a simulator?

Comment: The reason Spehro is asking that is that this is one of those circuits that usually doesn't work well in a simulator. It can't start up without some kind of imbalance or noise, so it doesn't work in the case that everything is perfectly ideal.

Comment: Im building using tinkercad

Comment: So does that mean that certain circuits would not work as well using online simulators

Comment: @qwerty Yes. Circuits that are self-clocking, oscillating, etc are notorious and even with high-end, non-online simulators, they can pose difficulties. You might be able to get it to start using a tiny mismatch (e.g. 2.701k instead of 2.7k on one resistor), or it may require real-world noise to work.

Comment: @qwerty Yes, sometimes circuits work because parts are not identical, or there is noise, or some other imperfection. Simulators often assume parts are identical, there is no noise, etc., resulting in equilibrium in the simulated circuit that would not be stable in a real circuit.

Comment: What does each LED Vf do to the collector voltage?

Comment: I don’t know about TinkerCad, but IRL the top and bottom power strips on bread boards are not usually connected in the middle… If you zoom in on the image you can see small vertical lines…

Comment: @Tyler I've never seen a breadboard that had those separated.

Comment: @Hearth they exist alright. I am looking at one right now (new item bought off eBay ~2 years ago). Unlike all my other breadboards this one has a larger gap in the middle of the power rails, like the one in the question. But does tinkercad simulate this division? The schematic suggests not.

Comment: @Hearth, I know I owned at least one breadboard where the power rails were divided like that, but it came out-of-the-box with jumpers already installed to connect them end-to-end.

Comment: Beside other issues, the initial condition of the capacitors may prevent starting the sequence (ex. Vc1=9V, Vc2=0, Vc3=0)".

Comment: I'd have expected the LEDs to be wired in series with the collector loads, not in shunt with the transistors. However, while wasteful of power, as there is current in the 2k7s all the time, I'd still expect it to clock. What voltages are you seeing on the 3 collectors? Are the caps the right way round, in terms of + to the collector - to the base? And why the red/black links at the RH end of the breadboard?

Answer (score 1):

I re-arranged cct. for 3 phase symmetry but asymmetry is due on cap values due to Vf on green has ~ 50% more swing than R/Y which affects ramp time of the next phase and made Yellow shorter by choice.

Otherwise with equal C values, Y=43% d.c. and R/Y=~ 28%.

Note f and duty cycle.

Falstad’s simplifies and thus speeds up [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwrGsQCYWQGwA4kHZsYCxgCMYAzKWSPFVRLAKYC0RRAUAO7KEj4bIZ9e4Dv0F9yaHnzAiJUkKQLyZAJ1HykAkEWySIOGKzVJuQkxB17tMG0YWlJQuZfDWbqhUqdKX%207Ic5FfG1dT2DzYQAXe0kkWEkg5HjXIihYHVgUUgBOfGxsjEViKDQcDDBcrFh8Umx8RBIIABN6ADMAQwBXABtIkQiXOTi9WQcQx1IkJJHOTT4XOa4IGQAlJY1uIisIbmzXZchYVgBzdRwpxYpg5ZOw5GwpxKv91gAPLgvipFLkMGDgrYgADCbHepHwqSQCAUaEhYEE2kkQKQby4fBM6LQeziqQBkgAiqCFNwTAlYVw9niQPiUe8aujqPVsbBSDxEdTSKiaogoYJYDyWGzAUDOadeH4puKFH8XtEahdklLhikQMxIA80DktlDYHU0BVEGBIER0tl9fgsf4amQ9o0QC0Oj0%20pwpS4ldwPFKhK7Qn5DGp5fJA743LYXZMg%20VlCJA95-tIRJkGRMpr5E5pplQM5MbrMSckIjnhHmIEWkwooVF1srFsqLGkdNlcCw0NgMrpWUbSm3YLksUR6uDknaHV1eqwoditAtNr6oO5soul8uV3tGEb0hhu0QKCxe9hddptBOKlILKFg3OjTZyNpIDiiNlvkgWOR4ngj2xJ3dBmMQ9eYFvddoAhVtyAwR9YAwbIcjIBpj3BEBWnYJoVAAewABwAHQARyQY0j2ySBJiYQVr3wSV70mE1sjAF80BqcFUgOOjWG1HgzXWfBOPOZAkJQ9DsLwgjmP2aA2HYwh9FMGB7gufjUMw3D8NSVSxOIVhEOQxShNIYjCOIpBSOYkCpjQdB4BZeIEBqbIrPUlF2OeQsZV4qZtME3C9M7I8WLYQJXJJLQIhkALwgeM4ItCnhZMLJQQpjWKIsSXjou42JTCjBKXR4iKlSi1hCFZRhOIjFhUyfVxyAAfXSJBqrAaqdzANA0Gq-CkEXeItjNGCd1ahroBgIgGva6qatIaqQVYNCKyoIgzJAV5oPKu8MDwbId1qTBMFyFr52GlUN1VEg9hWegmhmkA%20DqkBJGWgAjVaiEgdatxNC0HHIU6DuKetjuYU8AE16G6bo0PYK6UHmxbls2haaCNUSTMQErEAAcRUeh6AAO1YIA) by using a fixed hFE which normally drops to around 10% as a switch. I used beta=100.

[image]

This is basically same as your schematic in Tinker CAD but with more options in Falstad.